# How to catch end of html manipulations in KendoGrid after read()?

Tags: javascript, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have KendoGrid and want to detect end of all manipulations (including manipulations with html) after read(). How can I catch this event?

I have tried to use RequestEnd event with type "read", but after catching this event Kendo changes some html code in page.

**Update after adding databound**

I have KendoSortable, binded to KendoGrid, which contains column with positions. After position changes (onChange function), I need to block page (showLoader func) and update positions. As positions have changed, grid data (column with positions) must be reload by read(). And AFTER read() I need to unblock page by hideLoader. So, now, if I don't unbind onDataBound, my page is unblocked after remove/insert.

```
function onDataBound(e) {
        if (ir == 0) {
            updatePostion();
        }
        else {
            hideLoader(); 
        }
        ir++; 
    }

function onChange(e) {                            
        var grid = $("#TestQuestionAnswerList").data("kendoGrid");

        grid.unbind("dataBound");
        var newIndex = e.newIndex;
        var dataItem = grid.dataSource.getByUid(e.item.data("uid"));                           

        grid.dataSource.remove(dataItem);
        grid.dataSource.insert(newIndex, dataItem);
        grid.bind("dataBound", onDataBound);

        showLoader(); 
        updatePostion(); 
}

function updatePostion() {
        if (@Model.Type == 3) {
            var positions = [];
            grid._data.forEach(function (entry) {
                positions.push(entry.ID);
            });
            var dataToPost = { positions: positions, questionID: @Model.ID };
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("ChangePositions", "Testing")',
                type: 'POST',
                data: JSON.stringify(dataToPost),
                datatype: 'json',
                cache: false,
                contentType: "application/jsonrequest; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (data) {
                    grid.dataSource.read();
                },
                error: function () {
                    hideLoader();
                    alert("error");
                }
            });
        }
        else {
            grid.dataSource.read(); 
        }
    }
```

Comment: So you are looking for the event `DataBound`? See https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/events/databound for the documentation.

Comment: @CarstenFranke, thanks, it helps to solve my problem, but I have some other dataBound operations (insert/remove) and so I need to bind/unbind this event handler, when I use its. Can I detect only "read" operation?

Comment: Nope, the `DataBound` event does not tell you why it is called. What exactly do you want to achieve? Posting some code may be helpful as well.

Comment: @CarstenFranke, add some code and information about my problem in question